# Can an email contain multiple Message Ids?

Tags: java, email

I am implementing a mail client in java and I am retrieving the MessageId using the command: `String[] msgIds = msg.getHeader("Message-Id");`

Since `getHeader()` returns an Array. I was wondering if there is any scenario where an email might contain multiple Ids.

I tried testing it by sending/replying/forwarding an email back and forth but it only contained one id every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current specification for internet email message format is [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322).  That specifies that an email message can have zero or one "message-id" headers, and that one is recommended.  (See page 20 in the linked version)

So any email that has more than one "message-id" header is non-conformant.

However, if you are implementing a mail reader or processor, it is advisable to allow for the possibility of a non-conformant email message.  At the very least, your processor should cope with such an email so that it doesn't crash or behave in a destructive fashion.  (That kind of fragility could allow someone to attack your mail processor, and maybe the system that it runs on.)

Answer (score 2):

An E-Mail might not contain multiple `Message-Id` headers but other E-Mail header fields might appear multiple times. The getHeader function is returning an array to take these into account.

For example the `Recieved` header can be set multiple times to provide a full trace of servers that handled the E-Mail.